# Extract Graphics properties using EventHandler

Tags: graphics, eventhandler

One can find primitives' properties such as the radius, the center or the color of a [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Disk.html) using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) by using:

```
g = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Black, Disk[{10, 0}, 5], Blue, Disk[{30, 0}, 3]}]
Cases[g, Disk[_, y_] :> y, Infinity]
Cases[g, Disk[x_, _] :> x, Infinity]
Cases[g, _RGBColor | _Hue | _GrayLevel, Infinity]
```

yielding the right values.

How can the same functions be applied to an [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html)?

Consider for instance the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{list = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}},
 Graphics[
  EventHandler[
   {Red, Dynamic@Disk[#, 1] & /@ list},
  {"MouseClicked" :> {(* the appropriate function *)}}]]]
```

The aim would be the extract the radius/center/color of the clicked primitive.

Comment: Regarding Michael deleted comment: it's wrapped in `Dynamic` because the radius is meant to change when clicked in the "real" case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, using the built-in event handler `Button`:

```
DynamicModule[{list = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, res}, 
 Dynamic@{res, 
   Graphics[{Red, Button[Dynamic@Disk[#, 1], res = #] & /@ list}]}
 ]
```

An illustration of the use-case in the OP's comment to the question:

```
DynamicModule[{list = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, r},
 (r[#] = 1) & /@ list;
 Graphics[
   {Red, 
    Button[Dynamic@Disk[#, r[#]],
           r[#] = 1.5 + #[[1]]/2 - r[#]] &   /@ list},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 3.5}, {-2, 2}}]
 ]
```

Comment: Except that in this case you extract the centers of both when clicked, not the center of the clicked one.

Comment: @Öskå  Each disk buttons acts only when clicked now.  You can do whatever you want with the action argument to each button.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the notification since you first deleted your answer. There was no notification that you undeleted it. But thank you :)